# When will I get my followers?

Tags: diablo-iii

I'm still at the very beginning of Diablo 3, and I wonder when I will get my followers... Do they come all 3 at the same time, or do they come in one by one?

I do think I'll have a hard time soloing, so they might get handy real fast.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You rescue [Kormac the **Templar**](http://www.diablowiki.net/Templar) from cultists in the cathedral during the Act I quest [Reign of the Black King](http://www.diablowiki.com/Reign_of_the_Black_King).

[Lyndon the **Scoundrel**](http://www.diablowiki.com/Scoundrel) is met trying to con some artifacts from a woman and her village during the first part of The Broken Blade.

Early in Act II, in the first half of Shadows in the Desert, you meet the [Eirena the **Enchantress**](http://www.diablowiki.com/Enchantress) who clears illusions away that hide cultists.

As for the [camp followers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_follower) (Artisans), [*The Blacksmith*, Haedrig Eamon](http://www.diablowiki.com/Blacksmith) points you to where the crown is in Act I and he joins your crusade after you find it.  [*The Jeweler*, Covetous Shen](http://www.diablowiki.com/Jeweler) shows up in Act II hiding in a barrel.

Comment: Artisans are "camp followers"?  The mind boggles... ;)

Comment: @dlanod in [a broader sense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Camp_follower)

Answer (score 1):

They come at different times in the story.  You find the Templar first, relatively early on, on the Third Floor of the Cathedral during the quest Reign of the Black King.

The Scoundrel is found in the fields outside New Tristram while searching pieces of the Stranger's Sword.

The Enchantress is first encountered at the start of Act 2.

Comment: So basically you have everything on Act2.